# Should I use EventArgs or a simple data type?

Tags: c#, .net, events, coding-style, standards

I'm currently creating a library for fun and practice and I was wondering, when raising an event, how to choose between passing your own EventArgs derivative or just the data type.

For example, in my library I have something like this:

```
public delegate void LostConnectionEventHandler(string address);
public delegate void MessageReceieved(byte[] bytes);
```

What is the standard practice for this? Should I replace `string address` with `ConnectionEventArgs` and `byte[] bytes` with `MessageEventArgs`?

I know either one works just fine and this question may be subjective but I am still curious on the thought process higher-level programmers go through when deciding whether or not to include their own EventArgs or just to pass the data in directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The .NET Framework guidelines indicate that the delegate type used for
>   an event should take two parameters, an "object source" parameter
>   indicating the source of the event, and an "e" parameter that
>   encapsulates any additional information about the event. The type of
>   the "e" parameter should derive from the EventArgs class. For events
>   that do not use any additional information, the .NET Framework has
>   already defined an appropriate delegate type: EventHandler.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Another useful information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011.aspx

Comment: bravo, exactly the piece of documentation I was looking for and I forgot to include in my answer ;-)

Comment: This is outdated.  Current guidance is to use the generic EventHandler<> delegate type.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I like the idea of deriving from `EventArgs`,

if you have to pass status information and aggregate objects you could easily do it, see the

[MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx) type for example.

using OOP approach, if you have an event/construct which accepts an object of type `EventArgs` you can rely on the fact that every object derived from it will work in the same way while if you have another kind of object which does not share the same base class, you could eventually break something.

hard to prove and reproduce but possible depending on the design, because events are special delegates designed to work with `EventArgs` and its descendants

Answer (score 2):

In a larger project, having an EventArgs class, helps with minimizing the code you have to modify, when your event needs additional data in some cases. I usually prefere the EventArgs way instead of a direct value.

Comment: Of course you could ask the sender for the changed value, but maybe the changed value is already changed again, meaning that you missed the changed value. For instance if a camera captures pictures in a high speed, then every picture should be sent to the listeners, instead of the listeners asking for the last picture. Only if it is guaranteed that the sender won't change while the events are handled then you could use your method, but if you want independency between  the handling of events and the changeability of the sender, than you'll have to send the data together with the event.

Answer (score 0):

Within my projects I use EventArgs when the number of parameters is larger than one! Look at the NotifyPropertyChanged Event, it has one argument, which isn't an EventArgs type.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventhandler.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to derive from `EventArgs` however the convention follows the common ([Introduce Parameter Object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html)) refactoring rule. And the rationale for this rule is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

**I generally disagree with the "hide your args" guideline.** Hiding arguments in a contrived object removes a lot of meaning and context from the event signature, making developers hunt for it. And why? Just to avoid something we do all the time with methods: update call sites when an argument is added. That's just not a big deal. If it were, we'd also hide method arguments in a "MethodArgs" parameter. The readability loss isn't worth it in most cases.